# Programmatically set individual google slides advance time

Tags: google-slides-api, google-slides

I was wondering if there is a way to control how long I want my google slide to stay on the screen. The main use case for me is:

I want my presentation with 3 slides to show slide #1 for 5sec. , slide #2 for 10sec and slide #3 for 40sec.

I am not sure how to do so and if it is possible at all or not.

Maybe there is a hack that I can do when I embed or present the presentation to my web app if those settings are not available on the slides setup level?

Thanks.
Alexey.

Answer (score 0):

So far these are the operation that is achievable in Slide operations as per the example from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/slides/samples/slides#top_of_page). [Copy a slide](https://developers.google.com/slides/samples/slides#copy_a_slide), [Create a new slide](https://developers.google.com/slides/samples/slides#create_a_new_slide), [Create a new slide and modify placeholders](https://developers.google.com/slides/samples/slides#create_a_new_slide_and_modify_placeholders), [Move slides to a new position](https://developers.google.com/slides/samples/slides#move_slides_to_a_new_position), [Set a slide background image](https://developers.google.com/slides/samples/slides#set_a_slide_background_image). If you needed this function, you may file to [Request a new feature](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191598&template=823918). Or this [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761236) will suffice.